# How can I make Google Colab recognize my paid subscription for deep face lab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I paid for a subscription, but it is not displayed in Google in the purchase sections and the colab does not see it, where can I see my subscription?

I tried to install deep face lab but got an error, after which I bought a subscription but it was not displayed anywhere